# Code-Cleanup in VS2022 applies different tab/space formatting rules for closed solution files

Tags: visual-studio-2022, code-cleanup

Why would the VS2022 Code-Cleanup feature apply different keep-tabs formatting preferences depending on whether a source file is being viewed in VS2022 or is closed?

I have a new VS2022 install on a new Windows 11 dev machine and Resharper is not installed.

With all c-sharp source code windows closed, when I manually run Code-Cleanup all tab characters are converted to spaces. If I then open all source code files in VS2022 and run cleanup again, the spaces are converted back to tabs which is my Tools/Options keep-tabs preference.

I have 'view white-space' enabled and can see the indentation of my sourcde code flipping between tabs and spaces. This problem is repeatable.

Tools/Options 'Use adaptive formatting' is also disabled. I do not believe an .editorconfig settings file is applicable to my solution but even if there was a config file the open/close tabs/spaces formatting flip would be peculiar.